# How to save buffer (preferably if changed) and then close the buffer but not VIM?

Tags: vim

So, I just realized I could use marks with capital letters to go to different files. That's great! However, I'm trying to find a way to close the buffer and return to the previous one. Say I go to my header file to change or add the declaration of the function I'm writing, and then I'd like to save the file, but only if there's changes to it, to go back to working on the contents of the function. How can I do this?

- There's `:x`, but it also quits VIM
- There's `:bd!`, but it doesnt save the changes
- There's `:bw`, but that's even worse (unfortunately that's w[ipeout], not w[rite]...)
- There's `ctrl+O`, but it doesnt seem to work when I edit the file (also, it doesnt actually close the buffer)
- There's `:up` followed by `:bd`, but that's two commands and VIM's about efficiency, so I'd prefer a single command if it exists
- There's a few other options and variants, but none that do what I wanted, afaik

It feels like this should be simple enough to do with one command, preferably without macros/plugins/functions/snippets/etc; as close to vanilla as possible. I get the feeling I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could concatenate commands like so:

```
:w|bd
```

Comment: Yeah, seems that's the closest it gets. Thanks!

Comment: You could always create a shortcut for it if you use these commands a lot ;)

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to save the file, but only if there's changes to it

```
:up[date]
```

> to go back to working on the contents of the function

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>^</kbd>, or enter the command `:e[dit] #`

> I'd prefer a single command if it exists

Set an option `:set autowrite` and then Vim will save the current buffer on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> automatically.